# Is it better to name C# properties exactly as property type or take a shorter string?

Tags: c#, properties, naming-conventions

Consider following code

```
class ProductDefinition {}
```

A:

```
class Product { public ProductDefinition Definition {get;set}}
```

B:

```
class Product { public ProductDefinition ProductDefinition {get;set}}
```

(B) will result in slight redundancy when using this property such as

```
product.ProductDefinition.Price
```

vs

```
product.Definition.Price
```

However it seems to be something that programmers are used to see.

Are there any further elaborations on this topic?

Comment: [Primary opinion based.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: In this case I would prefer the "Definition" property as it is a Property of class Product it is clear that it is a Definition for the product. Additionally you shouldn't Name Properties with a Name that is also a type.

Comment: I would suggest to follow [Microsoft recommended guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx). Above all it depends on the team and opinion of the team members should also be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

It makes absolutely no sense to name your property `ProductDefinition` if your class is named `Product`. A property named `Definition` is of course the definition of `Product` (of what else?), so `ProductDefinition` would be redundand. And there is no practice of naming the proiperty like its type. C# allows that, but it does not mandate it.

The line...

```
product.Definition.Price
```

... is 100% clear and free of any redundancies. It's the price of the product's definition.

Comment: Others would argue that there is a benefit to know from the property name what type is returned. It's opionon based. A different example where it makes sense: `public Background {
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}`. Even microsoft [recommnends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx): _"CONSIDER giving a property the same name as its type"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That's basically hungarian notation (dressed in a tux). And your example is different. The naming equality of `Color` is coincidental, not intended. In the OPs case I would consider it defenitely bad style.

Comment: i don't think you have noticed that i have edited my comment. Even MS suggests to give property names which are equal to their types. But in my opinion you should decide from case to case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The convention also tells you to not use "s_" for static fields, while their own code analysis [says otherwise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164506.aspx). You have to take these formalistic conventions with a grain of salt (as MS does it). At the end, semantics count.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You are right though that the convention is out there, so I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `class Product { public ProductDefinition ProductDefinition {get;set}}`.
Because maybe in the future you wish to add another Definition to your class, and then you could have incongruencies in your property naming, because you would have one `Definition` and one `FooDefinition`. I think it is better to have `FooDefinition` and `BarDefinition`.

Comment: thanks, good point.

Comment: Be weary of programming for future possible requirements. They usually never come (while something else you have not thought of will come up). It's usually preferrable to go with the simple solution and refactor if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [Microsoft recommended guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx)

> ✓ **CONSIDER** giving a property the same name as its type. For example,
>   the following property correctly gets and sets an enum value named
>   Color, so the property is named Color:
>
> ```
> public enum Color {...}
> public class Control {
>     public Color Color { get {...} set {...} }
> }
> ```

So, in this case, I would structure it as:

```
class ProductDefinition {}
class Product { public ProductDefinition ProductDefinition { get; set; } }
```

---

### EDITED:

- Another point which I would take into consideration is having some other property which gives another definition to the `Product` object. For example (`ProductOwnerDefinition`):

> ```
> class ProductDefinition { }
> class ProductOwnerDefinition { }
> class Product
> {
>     public ProductDefinition ProductDefinition { get; set; }
>     public ProductOwnerDefinition ProductOwnerDefinition { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Here the usage of `Definition` can lead to confusion. So it is better to name the Property as the name of the type.

- Let's also consider another scenario, where we are using static code analysis tools like StyleCop. In this case, if we are not following the recommended patterns it will give suggestion on making modifications. This is not a big deal as we can suppress these rules. But, something to consider moving forward.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing: considering xD

Comment: BTW, their example is not so good - if you tell me 'color of control' I will be really confused, because (at least in the general or winforms/wpf context) I expect control to have more than one color.

Comment: Agree that this particular example from Microsoft can lead to a bit of *confusion* say we have *BackgroundColor*, *ForegroundColor* etc. But in your case, it makes sense I believe, let's say, you have a new *Property* of Type *ProductOwnerDefinition* in *Product* - Here I would name the property as the Type so that it makes it more clear.

Comment: Another thing which I would consider is usage of Code analysis tools like StyleCop in the application and if we have one in our project it might *bark* at us for not following the right patterns. But at the end of the day, it is us developers who should have more control on the way we should structure.